# Return Object in Array if Property Match

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, underscore.js

**Here is the scenario:**

- There is a parameter titled`listOfSelectedProductIds`that contains
  all of the selected ids.
- There is another list titled `listOfAllPossibleProducts`, which
  contains a list of `objects`. That `object` contains a `ProductId`,
  `ProductName`, and `ProductCode`. It looks something like this:

[image]

**The task at hand:**

- I need to loop through my `listOfSelectedProductIds`. If the `ProductId` matches a `ProductId` from `listOfAllPossibleProducts`, then I need to return that object.

**Here is what I am doing:**

```
function SelectedProducts(listOfSelectedProductIds){
    for (var index = 0; index < listOfSelectedProductIds.length; index++) {
        var currentItem = listOfSelectedProductIds[index];

        var desiredProduct = _.contains(listOfAllPossibleProducts, currentItem);

        if (desiredProduct === true) {
            return listOfAllPossibleProducts[index];
        }
    }
}
```

**What's currently happening:**

- My loop is getting the selected id as expected i.e. `currentItem`, but `_.contains(...)`
  always returns false.

**Question:**

- What is the best way to find the objects in
  `listOfAllPossibleProducts` that have `ProductIds` that match my
  `ProductIds` in the `listOfSelectedProductIds`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `_.filter`:

```
var result = _.filter(listOfAllPossibleProducts, function (el) {
  return _.contains(listOfSelectedProductIds, el.id);
});
```

Or the non-underscore method:

```
var result = listOfAllPossibleProducts.filter(function (el) {
  return listOfSelectedProductIds.indexOf(el.id) > -1;
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d27q0360/)

Comment: Wow, this is a slick answer... Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

create another structure `productsByProductId` **once!**

```
var productsByProductId = {};
listOfAllPossibleProducts.forEach(p => {
    productsByProductId[p.ProductId()] = p
});
```

and maybe a helper function

```
function getProductById(id){
    return productsByProductId[id];
}
```

and use this to map the ids to the nodes

```
var selectedProducts = listOfSelectedProductIds.map(getProductById)
```